# Use NiFi 1.5.0 processor in NiFi 1.2.0

Tags: apache-nifi

There is one particular processor as mentioned below I am interested in which has one extra feature in **1.5.0** as compared to **1.2.0** and so I want to use that.

**Processor Name:** QueryDatabaseTable

Is there any way I can just upgrade the processor or add this processor without upgrading whole NiFi?

I see there are two approaches.

1. Above processor is stored as the nifi-standard-nar-x.x.x.nar-unpacked file. So just copy the Nar from 1.5.0 and put it on 1.2.0. I am not sure after this if nifi will recognize this new processor version or not?
2. above processor is part of the following file, and so create a new processor out of it and deploye it on 1.2.0, not sure how complicated it will be though. 
   https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/dd58a376c9050bdb280e29125cce4c55701b29df/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/test/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/QueryDatabaseTableTest.java

would someone let me know which would be a better version and also, where I can find the **nar** file or **source code** of above processor, I don't separate nar file for this processor?

Comment: for sure nar copy will fail. cause it's one of the basic nars of nifi and it contains a lot of standard processors. [creating a custom processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932093/how-to-create-custom-processor-in-nifi) is not so hard if you are java dev. the sources are on [github](https://github.com/apache/nifi).

Answer (score 5):

It might be worth a try to simply copy in the NAR, but in this case I'm pretty sure it won't work. There were lots of core framework changes between 1.2.0 and 1.5.0, and also the standard NAR has the standard-services-api NAR as a dependency, so you'd likely need to copy that one as well, etc.

A general approach for backporting is to find the Jira case that has the feature/fix you want, use the link in the Jira to get to the Github Pull Request that added/fixed it, then create a branch from your baseline (nifi-1.2.0, e.g.) and cherry-pick the commits. If the changes are to a single bundle, you can simply build that NAR from the POM in its bundle directory (nifi-standard-bundle, e.g.). Then you can replace your existing NAR with the one you built, creating a kind of "hotfix NAR".

Answer (score 0):

I would think this is mainly an addition to the existing answer, but in general it is possible to create new processors. As such it may be wise to create a 'QueryDatabaseTable2' processor which is the same as the new one (or similar to it).